# Extract links from html page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to extract some articles from the Piography website.

so from this page http://www.biography.com/people I need all the sublinks.
for example:

```
 /people/ryan-seacrest-21095899
 /people/edgar-allan-poe-9443160
```

but I have two problems:

1- when I am trying to a find all < a >. I couldn't find the href that I need.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.biography.com/people"
text = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
divs = soup.findAll('a')
for div in divs:
    print(div)
```

2- There are a "see more" button. so how I can take all the links for all the people in the website. not just that appear in the first page?

Comment: You 'll have to use selenium for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On site what you show, use angular and part of content generate with JS. BeautifulSoup not execute JS. You need to use http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ or another like instrument. Or you may pry in ajax need for you GET(or may be POST) method, and give data through him.

Comment: Great post, I'd suggest using PhantomJS with Selenium. You can also parse the page with BeautifulSoup managing Selenium source using the method 
driver.page_source
and execute specific JS with .execute_script 
or get html with .get_attribute(